# VB: Search in String

Tags: vb.net

How do I search in a string from ";" to ";"?

```
Dim strInput as String = "text1;text2;text3"
```

Solution should look like this:

```
strOutput1 = "text1"
strOutput2 = "text2"
strOutput3 = "text3"
```

The lenght of the single "parts" is not fix, strInput can also be like "12345;name;Christoph;"

I just want to get the parts in a own string. 
Does anybody knows how to?

Comment: See String.Split() https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: not sure why the down votes.  Some people are intolerant of people just starting out and asking basic questions.  Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way is probably using `SPLIT` to populate an array then set the individual variables to each element in the array. The only issue that might arise is if you have ;'s inside the strings, but that would pretty much prevent anything not based on length.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your string:

```
Dim strInput as String = "text1;text2;text3"
```

Then do a split:

```
Dim inputArray() As String = Split(strInput, ";")
```

This will split your string up using ; as the delineator.  So you will end up with this:

```
inputArray(0) = "text1"
inputArray(1) = "text2"
inputArray(2) = "text3"
```

More on split()...

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Using .Split you can separate the original string into an array of strings like this

```
Dim strInput As String = "text1;text2;text3"
Dim tempStringList() As String = strInput.Split(";"c)
```

So now

tempStringList(0) contains "text1"

tempStringList(1) contains "text2"

and so on.

The beauty of .split is that it doesnt care how many sections there are to separate.